# Play current test case button stops working after custom function called

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I have a really strange error occurring when using Selenium IDE and that is when this function is called, any attempts to use the Play Current Test Case button no longer work

```
Selenium.prototype.doClickSearchTemplate = function (locator, action) {
profileToggleButton = null;
profileName = '';
$ = _getGlobalVar('jQuery');

var locator = locator || 'id=content';
/* Find where element is located (so parent div for example) */
var reportBlockContainer = this.page().findElement(locator);

//find labels and if text typed into selenium matches one of the elem's then click to change button selected
jQuery(reportBlockContainer).find('.reportBlockHeader h2 strong').each(function(index, elem) { 
    profileName = $.trim(jQuery(elem).text());
    if (profileName == action)  
        profileToggleButton = elem.parentNode.previousElementSibling; // previousSibling = jQuery(elem).parent().prev().get(0);
});

if (profileToggleButton === null)
    throw new SeleniumError("Invalid Search Template Name: " +action);

this.browserbot.clickElement(profileToggleButton);
};
```

Does anyone have any idea of why this would happen? The function works but its clearly clashing with something else? I'm just stumped with why

Thanks